# is it an infinite looping?(Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing a quiz on sololearn and I'm confused, it says I have to loop from 5 to 1 when I use hint I get this code and when I run the code it becomes infinite loop instead of looping from 5 to 1

is it an infinite looping?

```
x = 5
while x > 0:
    print(x)
x -= 1
```

Comment: put `x -= 1` inside the `while`

Comment: It should print 5 all the time ... why does this not clue you in on what is wrong?!?

Answer (score 1):

Python is sensitive to the indenting of code.  In order for your decrement statement to fall within the loop it must be indented to fall under the print statement.